# Unable to Install Rockstor from bootable USB

Tags: system-installation, bootable, nas

Motherboard: Supermicro X11SAE-F, BIOS 2.3
16GB ram
Processor: Xeon E3-1225 V6

I have 6 SSDs connected to the onboard SATA ports of the motherboard. All 6 drives are empty/new and have not been formatted.

When I plug in a bootable USB (tried with multiple USB sticks) with the Rockstor installation files and select the version to install (regular or failsafe), the installer begins to run, hangs for a while on dracut-initque, then spits out errors for a while and ends with `Warning: /dev/disk/by-label/INSTALL does not exist`. The installer then enters emergency mode, and I use Ctrl+D t continue, but after selecting the SSD I would like to use to install Rockstor I get a "Failed to mount install ISO device" message and the system restarts.

Comment: I don't know Rockstor, but that sounds like a broken USB installer. How did you create it? See [Making a Rockstor USB install disk](https://rockstor.com/docs/installation/quickstart.html#making-a-rockstor-usb-install-disk)

Comment: I created the installer using balenaEtcher